# Cannot upgrade pip in cygwing running on Windows 10: /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

Tags: python, cygwin, pip

In cygwin I can't upgrade pip, it worked find in cmd:
`$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
 /usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

Comment: @pak This seems to be the right answer! Why don't you post this comment as an answer to upvote it? The OP could consider it as the answer too. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Likely you don't need the `python -m` part. If pip is in your path, then just typing `pip install --upgrade pip` should work. Where is pip installed? `which pip` will tell you where it's located, if it's in your path